# How to order Data from a row properly

Tags: php, mysql, row

How can i order results from a mysql row. Currently my code is as such:

```
require 'dbconnect.php';

// Query the database
$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM wp_wppizza_orders");

    if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){
        // Turn the results into an Array
         while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
         {
            $id = $rows['id'];
            $klantgegevens = $rows['customer_details'];   
            $bestelling = $rows['order_details'];   
            $statusbetaling = $rows['payment_status'];   
            $printed = $rows['printed'];
            if ($printed == 1){
               $printed = "FINISHED";
            } else {
               $printed = "NEW";
            }
            echo "<p class = 'orders'>";
            echo "<b>Klant gegevens:</b> $klantgegevens <br /><b>Bestelling:</b> $bestelling<br /> <b>Betaal Status:</b> $statusbetaling <br /> <b>Order Status:</b> $printed <br /> <a href='delete.php?del=$id'>Delete</a> <a href='update.php?del=$id'>Bon</a>";
            echo "</p>";
         }
```

The result is such:

**Klant gegevens(customer details)**: Name : Swag Email : EnesDemirICT@gmail.com Address : Florisvosstraat 56 Telephone : +31685035990 Comments : Hi my name is jason bourne.

**Bestelling:** 1x Pizza A medium [£ 7.45] £ 7.45 1x Pizza B medium [£ 7.45] £ 7.45 1x Pizza C medium [£ 7.45] £ 7.45 your items £ 22.35 free delivery total £ 22.35

**Betaal Status:** COMPLETED

**Order Status:** FINISHED

Delete Bon

As you can see the customer details is just a mess, how can i order this so it looks neat. I had something like this in mind:

Name: *Name*

email: *email*

Adress: *adress*

Telephone: *telephone*

Comment: *comment*

**Editor's note:**  The issue is that the data is all stored in one variable on the database, and the database cannot be restructured.  The data needs to be pulled out of one variable and restructured as above.

Comment: Edit your question and actually include the query you are using.

Comment: typically you would order your rows in your sql query.

Comment: Your customer details are all in same database row?

Comment: yeah all the customer detail is in the same row

Comment: I would start by redesigning the database

Comment: While you would normally order  your data in your sql row, reading between the lines of what you are saying, you don't mean "order" but instead layout.   The issue is that you seem to have included all of your customer data in one row:  `$klantgegevens`.   Please show us how this row is constructed

Comment: Its just clear text. And yes you are right, layout would be a better name.

Comment: okay one way to handle this is with `preg_split`.  see the edit to my answer below

Comment: one more time, `preg_match` is both cleaner and easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all of your details in `$klantgegevens`, and that that data is all shown in one row.  That will cause you problems.

It appears you have not normalized your data in your database.  I suggest creating a table name something like `customerDetails` and then including rows such as `id`, `name`, `email`, etc

You query would look something like this:

```
$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM wp_wppizza_orders w
                           JOIN customerDetails c
                           ON w.id = c. id");
```

This way when you run your query, each of these will appear in a separate row, like this:

```
$name = $rows['name']; 
$email = $rows['email'];
```

This way when you echo out the rows, it will separate them correctly like so:

```
     while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo 'Name: '.$name.'<br/>';
            echo 'email: '.$email.'<br/>';
     }
```

**Edit:** :  Since you are forced to split apart a line of text, you may need to do something with regex.   Here's an example of how to create a variable for `name`.  Try this out.  You should be able to modify your code to handle something like this.

```
$klantgegevens = "Name : Swag Email : EnesDemirICT@gmail.com Address : Florisvosstraat 56 Telephone : +31685035990 Comments : Hi my name is jason bourne";
$names = preg_split('/Name :/', $klantgegevens);
array_shift($names);
echo "<pre>";
$name = print_r($names[0]);

echo $name;
```

You could do something similar for the remaining rows.

**Edit again:   Here's a much better way.**  We are just grabbing the rows in between the tags "Name" and "Email".  Much easier than dealing with preg_split.   The wildcard below is just shown with `(.*?)`

```
$klantgegevens = "Name : Swag Email : EnesDemirICT@gmail.com Address : Florisvosstraat 56 Telephone : +31685035990 Comments : Hi my name is jason bourne";
preg_match("'Name : (.*?)Email :'s", $klantgegevens, $name);
echo $name[1];
```

The only thing you need to do to get the other variables is to change the strings, such as change `Name :` to `Email :` and then `Email :` to `Address :`, etc.

Comment: I know that its much simpler this way, and i actually already did as such. But the assignment specificly requires me to have proper layout for this row. Its alway has to the hard way... :)

Comment: well, you could try using regular expressions.  but then you'd have 2 problems ;)

Comment: okay I played with this a bit, and added an example on how to split the rows as you have them.